# SharePoint Online Relative URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-integration

I am trying to figure out how to link a document library to Dynamics 365. When I try to "enable server-based SharePoint integration", it says that Absolute URL detected, and something about it no longer being supported. So, I am trying to find the relative URL but I have no idea how to get it. I need to get the relative URL of my SharePoint parent site and of the document library within the parent site.

I am on SharePoint Online that comes with Office 365 Business Professional, Plan 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please copy&paste the full error message you receive when running the SharePoint integration wizard? "Something about no longer being supported" is not detailled enough to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I feel this question isn't valid to some extent for this forum.

Still when you try to enable the "**server-based SharePoint integration**", are you logged as the global admin for your office 365 tenant? Also SharePoint and Dynamics 365 CRM have to be from the same office 365 tenant. When I did it, I used my SharePoint site URL as the 'Absolute URL' and a document library got created and synced automatically. There was nothing specific about 'Absolute URL' or 'Relative Url'. If it still doesn't works, you may try to troubleshoot this issue using the following post (from another forum):

[This](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/228321)

Hope that helps!